# Import excel to SQL Server getting Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED

Tags: excel

I AM RECIVING EROR:

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source 1 returned error code 0xC020902A.
The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

My Excel spreadsheet in one of the cells has multiple records similar to this one:

The buyer's xxx***XXX xxx***XXX xxx***XXX xxx***XXX xxx***XXX xxx***XXX "
Regretfully  YYY*** YY*** YY*** YY*** YY*** YY*** YY***.
My destination column is  nvarchar(MAX) NULL.

Any suggestion how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This fix the issue with similar problem in my case:

1. near the **Start** button press drop-down menu arrow
2. choose ***package_name* Debug Properties**
3. than under **Configuration Properties** open **Debugging**
4. than under **Debug Options** choose **Run64BitRuntime** and turn it to **False**